# For loop using enumerate runs more than expected for a pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

So, I was working on titanic dataset to extract Title(Mr,Ms,Mrs) from Name column from Data frame(df). Its has 1309 rows.

```
for ind,name in enumerate(df['Name']):
     if type(name)==str:
        inf = name.find(', ') + 2
        df.loc[ind+1,'Title'] = name[inf:name.find('.')]
    else :
        print(name,ind)
```

This peice of code gives the following output

> nan 1309

As supposed it had to stop for ind=1308, but it goes one step further even if not indicated to do so.
What could be the flaw here? Is it due to the fact that I am using 1 based indexing of the data frame?
If so, what could be done here to prevent such behaviour?
I am new to this platform, so please ask for clarifications in case of any discrepancies.
Here is a short Example:-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'Name':['Hey, Mr.','Hello, Ms.','Hi, Mrs,','Welcome, Master.','Yes, Mr.'],'ind':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = dict1)
df.set_index('ind')
for ind,name in enumerate(df['Name']):
    if type(name)==str:
        inf = name.find(', ') + 2
        df.loc[ind+1,'Title'] = name[inf:name.find('.')]
    else :
        print(name,ind)
        
print(df['Title'])
```

Comment: What is `print(len(df.Name))` giving?

Comment: Use [```df.iteritems()```](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) or [```df.iterrows()```](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) instead of ```enumerate()```

Comment: Clearly `df['Name']` is at least 1310 elements long.  Probably the last row contains a space or something, so it isn't finding a valid `name` for that row.

Comment: @MustafaAydın it is giving 1309

Comment: @TomKarzes that is not the case whole data frame is only 1309 elements long
It might be due to the way I have indexed the dataframe(1 based indexing) and enumerate might be starting from 0.

Comment: @Firebreather *It might be due to the way I have indexed the dataframe* That would not give the result you have unless you're doing something like  `ind += 1` in the loop; are you doing such a thing?

Comment: @MustafaAydın I am not doing any such thing! All the loop is shown in code.

Comment: @UncleJohn Okay, I now see you're enlargening the dataframe as you iterate over it via `df.loc[ind + 1...]`. That makes the dataframe 1310 rows but only at the end.. So still, within that loop, that printing seems not possible, but maybe after the loop. To clarify things, can you please post a [mcve] i.e., a small, perhaps mockup dataframe that shows the same issue, so that we can all run it?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Please have a look at the edit. Now I get some idea, It might be due to set_index function of pandas, which disturbs the row and indexes. Originally I read the data frame using index_cols which might differ in behaviour to set_index. Still Both have one NaN and 0.

Comment: @UncleJohn When I run that code, I don't get any print outputs...

Comment: @MustafaAydın There is an edit! Please try changing indentation if this doesn't work

Comment: @UncleJohn I think I see the overall issue now, it is this line: `df.set_index("ind")` which effectively does nothing because you didn't assign it back! If you instead do `df = df.set_index("ind")` there, do you get what you intended at the end?

Comment: ...(and also there *might* be more "pandaic" ways of what you're doing but that's not the main focus of the question I believe...)